# C# PixelComparison between images

Tags: c#, image, pixel

I'm trying to compare between 2 images,actually 2 screen shots i took from my destkop. These are the images

[image]
[image]

I wanted to check for changed pixels,so this is a simple method i wrote:

```
private void ProcessPixels(Bitmap bmp1,Bitmap bmp2)
    {

        for (int y = 0; y < bmp1.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bmp1.Width; x++)
            {
                if (bmp1.GetPixel(x, y) != bmp2.GetPixel(x, y))
                    bmp1.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);
            }
        }
    }
```

As a result, i  got somthing i wasn't really expecting for,the majority of the  changed pixels changed  changed to black pixel as i expected,but there were some pixels which didnt change to black...(even though they look different between the 2 images,but maybe they're just look equal but there not?)

This is the result image:
[image]
For example you can see in the opened windows start menu,that some pixels remain the same,and in the edges there also some odd parts.

Maybe i'm missing few pixels on the loop?

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: @FirstStep you don't what?

Comment: Examine where the blackness ends. It is a bit higher than @Slashy probably expects. If you look closely at the start menu it slightly darkens the edges where it fades  into the rest of the desktop, this is the difference you are seeing.

Comment: it should be  (bmp1.GetPixel(x, y) == bmp2.GetPixel(x, y)) to get the majority of the result pic black

Comment: @FirstStep Updated :)

Comment: The few pixels on the far right that are non-black look like they come from the overlap of "Steam" on the original image, and "Sway" on the second image. You should be able to figure this out easily enough. Just create an extra test so that if identical pixels are found in the overlapping area, you output the pixel values and the coordinates. Then you can check the source images to see if things are working as expected.

Comment: Blue tiles on a bluish background, ClearType anti-aliasing, what could possibly go wrong?  Think this through before you waste more time on this.

Comment: @HansPassant yeah.. i just disabled one of the windows effects..(show shadows under windows.. and it's getting better.. still tiny amount of pixels which remain the same but i can deal with it.. :(